# how do you use greendroid from the command line?

Tags: android

How would I integrate the GreenDroid library when not using eclipse for android development?

https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid

Answer (score 0):

There are instructions here: http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=240